# How to remove from a ArrayList<String> all elements other than text documents?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

In my code assumes that only should add to the list of items that end with ".txt" but the list shows all that is in X folder.

This is my code:

```
private void spinner_dos() {
    //ARRAY CON TITULOS DE ARCHIVOS TXT
    if (carpeta_para_leer == "Textos")
    {
        camino = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/" + carpeta_para_leer+ "/";
    }else{
        camino = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Textos/" + carpeta_para_leer+ "/";
    }
    try {
        File t = new File(camino);
        String[] lista_textos = t.list();
        lista_lista_textos = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String lista_texto : lista_textos) {
            if (lista_texto.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")) {
                lista_lista_textos.add(lista_texto);
            }
        }
        for (int index =0; index < lista_lista_textos.size(); index++){
            lista_lista_textos.set(index, WordUtils.capitalizeFully(lista_textos[index].toLowerCase().replace(".txt", "")));

        }
        Collections.sort(lista_lista_textos, new AlphanumComparator());
    }catch (Exception e){

    }

    if (lista_lista_textos.size() ==0 && ar.size() !=0){
        tv1.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tv1.setText("La carpeta seleccionada no contiene archivos de texto...");
                tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String[] array_blanco = new String[0];
                ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(EL_Entrenamiento.this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_blanco);
                adaptador.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
                spinner_fichero.setAdapter(adaptador);
            }
        });
        }else{
        tv1.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tv1.setText("");
                tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador_textos = new ArrayAdapter<String>(EL_Entrenamiento.this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lista_lista_textos);
        adaptador_textos.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
        spinner_fichero.setAdapter(adaptador_textos);
        spinner_fichero.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
```

What can I do to only add the items to the list if they ends with ".txt" or otherwise eliminate it?

Comment: The code looks correct to me. Are you sure you are displaying lista_lista_textos and not lista_textos or something else?

Comment: Seems your code is doing already what you describe.

Comment: For me, nothing wrong in this code.

Comment: I'm using this list in a spinner, I leave the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop:

```
for (int index =0; index < lista_lista_textos.size(); index++){
    lista_lista_textos.set(index, WordUtils.capitalizeFully(lista_textos[index].toLowerCase().replace(".txt", "")));
}
```

Essentially overwrites your `lista_lista_textos` with `lista_textos` uppercased. The indices will not match in the list and the array because you were not adding all of them. You should read from `lista_lista_textos.get(index)` instead.